# Get facebook user checkins

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-checkins

I need to get a list of a **facebook user checkins** both in **photos** and in **status**.

I tried to use graph api to query /me/locations' like:

```
$this->api->api('/me/locations?limit=1000');
```

It returns me a list of user checkins with three different types: photo, checkin or status.

My problem is that I need to get the photos that have user checkins but I can't seem to find it.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at the [User](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) documentation, under the title *feeds*, it lists a method of fetching only the posts which have a location (Checkin) in it.

> https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?with=location

As for getting *Photos* with a location (Checkin), there doesn't seem to be any documentation that suggests that the Photos can be filtered similar to the way Posts can be filtered. At best, I guess you will have to fetch all photos and then filter out the ones that do not have the **place** tag. Posts use the *location* tag while Photos use the *place* tag.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer but when I query https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos i get no place tag on any photo.

Comment: @jribeiro: Photos use the _place_ tag. Not the _location_ tag.

Comment: Yes. Any reason for no place tag returned when I query me/photos?fields=created_time,height,id,source,width,picture,places&limit=2500 ? And yes I have tagged some photos

Comment: @jribeiro: Try this: `/me/photos?fields=id,picture,place&type=uploaded&limit=2500` You can add more fields as per your requirements.

Comment: @jribeiro: Glad to have been of help. :-)

Comment: What if I want to get Check in data for my page?